# Get Textbox by id without looping. i have the id in a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, foreach

so i got this:

```
       foreach (DropDownList drp in pnl.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>())
    {
        if (drp.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string textboxMinValue = "minval";
            foreach (TextBox txt in pnl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                if (txt.ID == "txtStatMin" + drp.ID.Substring(6,1))
                {
                    if (txt.Text != "min")
                    {
                        textboxMinValue = txt.Text;
                        statMin.Add(textboxMinValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        statMin.Add(textboxMinValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            statName.Add(drp.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
```

i have a panel with drop downs and text boxes.  i loop through the drop downs, if something was selected, i need the value in a text box.  drop down id's are ddStat0 ddStat1 etc  textboxes are txtStatMin0 txtStatMin1 etc

i want to remove the foreach loop of the text boxes,  no reason to go through them all, i know which one i want. i cant grasp it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Control c = FindControl("Control_ID");
// Check for null and cast it:
TextBox t = (TextBox) c;
```

Comment: @I4V He must be thinking of [`System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/486wc64h.aspx)

Comment: @I4V Since he is writing in code behind no need to reference it. It is already there.

Comment: this is in a function, i have moved the function to a seperate cs file.  since i pass the panel that the controls are in, i dont have access to the findcontrol method.  i even tried system.web.ui.control.findcontrol,  its not there either, i am referencing system.web.ui.control

Comment: @user2070677: Add reference to assembly. After all in terms of performance `FindControl` will iterate all controls so this will just make the code cleaner.

Comment: ok, forgive me here... i right click my project, select add reference, and look on .net for a reference to...?  system.web.ui?  i dont see it.  if I say using System.Web.UI.WebControls, and i dont get an error saying im missing an assembly, i would assume that the reference is already there

Comment: @user2070677: Reference to `System.Web` assembly. It is in `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: @user2070677: This function is a member of `Control` class. Since it is not `Static` you need an instance of a web control. It seems your passed panel is the best choice (it inherits the method from `Control`) so use `panel.FindConrol(...)`